# Working of INSTALL_REFERRER Broadcast

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, android-broadcast

I want to know the correct working of the INSTALL_REFERRER Broadcast from referrals. This is to ensure its not possible to 'exploit' apps.

So far, this is what I have understood:

1. User gets the referral link of the app
2. User downloads on device
3. Just after installation, a broadcast is sent from Google Play app
4. This Broadcast is received by the app that is tracking the referral.

Will the broadcast be fired again if:

1. User downloads the app from same account, but another device
2. Uninstalls the app , installs it again (on same device)

Answer (score 0):

In general, as far as I know, it should fire in both of those cases. If you want to make sure to count it only once, you should check for a flag of some sort that you have on your own server.

Here is documentation to support this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver.html --

```
"The Google Play com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER Intent is 
broadcast when an app is installed from the Google Play Store. This 
BroadcastReceiver listens for that Intent, passing the install referrer 
data to GTM for Mobile Apps and Google Analytics."
```